# How to generate Entity-Relation diagram from SQL DDL?

Tags: sql, database-design, ddl, erd

For example DbVisualizer can be used to connect to a DB and create nice diagram out of existing tables and their relations. But in this specific case I do not have a live database but I have bunch of create table and alter statements.

Is there any tool to generate similar diagrams out of SQL DDL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that Embarcadero's ERStudio can import a SQL script into a diagram, but it's a pricey tool to use just for something like this. You could always just create an empty database and run the scripts then point to that.

Answer (score 9):

I found the MySQL tool MySQL Workbench to do a great job.  There is a Mac OS X version.  More information can be found at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/index-gui.html.

Comment: I used MySQL Workbench on Windows, it generates diagram. You can click on Arrange -> Autolayout. It arranges all the entities automatically. Very helpful.

Comment: If you already have an existing database, you can use `Database -> Reverse Engineer...` to create a graphical mode.

Answer (score 4):

SQLFairy will generate graphics from plain SQL DDL files:

http://sqlfairy.sourceforge.net/

Comment: example of usage to achieve that would be highly desired

Answer (score 3):

[Visual Paradigm for UML](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/highlight/reverseddl.jsp) can do this.