# SQL visualization software

Tags: sql, data-visualization

I have a large .sql file of tables -- is there software that can auto-generate visual clusters of tables (as they are related by foreign keys) based on a SQL file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How generate diagram from SQL DDL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/841541/how-generate-diagram-from-sql-ddl)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using MySQL, take a look at [MySQL Workbench](http://wb.mysql.com/).

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for some tools like this one: https://sqlflow.gudusoft.com/#/

It offers you the option to visualize the SQL as well as generate proper E-R diagram. You can either **upload the SQL file** or directly **paste your SQL statements**.

For more info you can check their doc:https://docs.gudusoft.com/1.-introduction/readme

Answer (score 1):

You need to google "Entity Relationship diagram" - there are several tools, many of them enterprise and expensive. I've used ErWin and StarDesigner.